# I have 2 js functions and one is canceling out the other

Tags: javascript

I looked through the FAQ but couldn't figure out what was causing this (in js). I'm trying to get something live soon and I'm bypassing better animation for the time being, possibly also AJAX.

What I'm going is bringing two external php pages a includes to the current page, one is a gallery slider and the other is where the gallery imagery will appear. Here is a link to the page I'm currently testing so you can see:

http://www.chrisjohndesigns.com/artwork-conventions.php

So the code I've used has been simple replacement .innerHTML calls where the left and right arrows call the next gallery div and then the thumbnails within that gallery call the artwork that appears below. The left and right arrows work just fine but as soon as any of the thumbnails are clicked (and they do work properly) the left and right arrows stop working and you're stuck on whatever frame you chose from.

Here is the code from the conventions page:

```
  <div id="field">
    <div id="gallery-callout">
      <div class="thumbs-slider-field-container" id="generic-slider">
        <div class="thumbs-slider-field" >
          <div id="prev">
            <img src="images/gallery-scroll-left.png" width="42" height="120" />
          </div>
          <div id="thumbs-slider">
            <img src="images/thumbs/digital-art/thumb-space-oddity.jpg" id="thumb-space-odity" onclick="changeDiv('space-oddity')"/>
           <img src="images/thumbs/digital-art/thumb-atomic-nurse.jpg" id="thumb-nurse" onclick="changeDiv('nurse')"/>
           <img src="images/thumbs/digital-art/thumb-zombie-make-over.jpg" id="thumb-zombie-makeover" onclick="changeDiv('zombie-makeover')"/> 
           <img src="images/thumbs/digital-art/thumb-fanart-trigun.jpg" id="thumb-trigun" onclick="changeDiv('trigun')"/>
           <img src="images/thumbs/digital-art/thumb-shadowrun.jpg" id="thumb-shadowrun" onclick="changeDiv('shadowrun')"/> 
         </div>
         <div id="next">
           <img src="images/gallery-scroll-left.png" width="42" height="120"  onclick="callSlider('conventions2')" />
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rule">
  </div>
  <div class="entry" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
    <h4 style="color:#ffffff; margin:0px;">| <a href="artwork.php"> artwork </a> > <a href="artwork-conventions.php"> conventions</a></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-frame" id="generic">
    <h1 style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:10px;">CONVENTION ARTWORK</h1>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="images/artwork/portfolio-design/logos/atomic-heart/atomicH-heart_0910.png" />  
    </div>
    <div class="rule">
  </div>
  <p>Here you will find arwork produced for (or for sale at) the conventions that Atomic Glam attends. Our premier convention is Anime Weekend Atlanta held in Atlanta each September.<br />(Above: The Atomic Heart Logo of Atomic Glam)</p>

  <div style="display:none;">
    <?php include("artwork-gallery-digital.php"); ?>
    <?php include("sliders/slider-artwork-conventions.php"); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

The js I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
altViews = function(next_img) {
    document.getElementById("bigPicture").src = next_img;
}

function changeDiv(id) {
var target = document.getElementById('generic');
var id = document.getElementById(id);
target.innerHTML = id.innerHTML; 
}

function callSlider(slides) {
var target2 = document.getElementById('generic-slider');
var slides = document.getElementById(slides);
target2.innerHTML = slides.innerHTML; 
}

</script>
```

An example of the slider:

```
<div class="thumbs-slider-field" id="conventions1">
  <div id="prev">
    <img src="../images/gallery-scroll-left.png" width="42" height="120" />
  </div>
  <div id="thumbs-slider">
    <img src="../images/thumbs/digital-art/thumb-space-oddity.jpg" id="thumb-space-odity" onclick="changeDiv('space-oddity')"/>
    <img src="../images/thumbs/digital-art/thumb-atomic-nurse.jpg" id="thumb-nurse" onclick="changeDiv('nurse')"/>
    <img src="../images/thumbs/digital-art/thumb-zombie-make-over.jpg" id="thumb-zombie-makeover" onclick="changeDiv('zombie-makeover')"/> 
    <img src="../images/thumbs/digital-art/thumb-fanart-trigun.jpg" id="thumb-trigun" onclick="changeDiv('trigun')"/>
    <img src="../images/thumbs/digital-art/thumb-shadowrun.jpg" id="thumb-shadowrun" onclick="changeDiv('shadowrun')"/> 
  </div>
  <div id="next">
    <img src="../images/gallery-scroll-left.png" width="42" height="120"  onclick="callSlider('conventions2')" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Any thoughts why one is canceling out the other?

Comment: the link up the top gives a 404

Comment: Is the full HTML code relevant? If not, please remove it, or reindent it so the relevant parts are highlighted. Also, where are you attaching the event handlers? Where is that script placed?

Comment: @Bergi - They're inline. Gerard, take the `2` out of the url.

Comment: OP, open a Javascript console and look at the errors when you click the scroll thumbs buttons. `slides is null`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Thanks, haven't seen them.

Comment: You are redefining your function parameters in changeDiv and callSlider

Comment: @Gerard, sorry about that, I took the 2 out and must not have updated the post. You say i'm redefining my paramaters, but I thought I named them differently. What do I do to separate them?

Comment: @Bergi I removed the additional code. I didn't know how much would be needed to view but I left only the two divs in question and their container

Comment: @Jared, thanks for fixing the link. I'm really learning this as I go and while I've come across 'null' I'm not entirely sure what it means -rahter what I've done to cause it. Is it in relation to Gerard's comment about redefining the function parameters?

Comment: @user1311848: If [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById) returns `null` it means that there is no element with that id [found].

Comment: Ok, finally I think I see what @GerardSexton was saying, which I think is possibly the problem. You have an argument of `slides`, *then* you have `var slides` defined inside the function itself. **Don't do this.** Remove the `var` and you'll simply redefine the `slides` argument, or create a new `var slide = ...` (do not remove the `var` in this case, though).

Comment: I've had very little luck so far in trying to do an animated slider, but if there is as easier way to tell the left and right arrows to just advance to the next div I'd prefer to do that. I was trying to set the thumbnails as an array but while I could source them I wasn't sure how I could give them the onclick="changeDiv" function. Everything I've read just shows me how to call a url

Comment: @jaredfarrish, so once I use the changeDiv function it's redefining the variable as the changeDiv id and not recognizing the callSlider function? I tried taking var out but still didn't work though. What is the difference between var and not having var?

Comment: Using `.innerHTML` to copy and insert from one place to another causes issues, one of which have to do with event handlers. Why don't you find a pre-built gallery and use that? If this were me, I'd do it differently anyway.

Comment: What I really want to do is set the thumbnails in an array and define it so that clicking the left button shifts the left pos -500px and the right shifts the array 500px right with each click.

But I haven't found any basic animation tutorials that cover something like that.

Comment: Why not use a preexisting library? [Galleria is pretty good](http://galleria.io/) and well-documented. jQuery also has several very good galleries like [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/demos/4/).

Comment: Here's an example of doing it a different way: http://jsfiddle.net/nFXHa/embedded/result/ ([source](http://jsfiddle.net/nFXHa/)) Note, I did not try to emulate the style you have here, but note this is more like what you had suggested, only you don't have to struggle with the cruft of floating elements or whatnot. This just changes the `margin-top` of a container element. This is for demonstration purposes as well, so note I've hardcoded some things that could be dynamic (like the non-thumb url and the width/height of the container and rows).

Comment: Also note that apparently IE does not support microdata format (`data-full` for the non-thumb url in my fiddle). You could actually use the `img.src` value if you can simply remove a part of the url like `/thumb` and you have the non-thumb url.

Comment: And @JaredFarrish, thanks for the assist with that stuff on jsfiddle. I messed with that a bit and it's working exactly how I needed it to!